# Using python 3x, is there a way to shift lines in a file to a specific column and make every line (except the last line) of equal length?

Tags: python, file, replace, format

The best way I can make this question more comprehensible is by the following example.

I want to change "File 1" to "File 2".

File 1

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
         4  5  6  7  8  9  
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

File 2

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
4  5  6  7  8  9  1  2  3   #Note that 4 was shifted to the first column of the 2nd row
4  5  6  7  8  9            #All numbers after 4 were shifted to complete the middle line
```

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Are there any special features in Python 3x that can solve this problem?

I have tried searching for this problem here, but could not find a relevant solution. I apologize if this was already asked.

I began to solve this problem by extracting the elements of interest from the file and store them into an array (e.g. store all numbers in 'File 1" into an array). However, I have trouble moving to the next step, which is to print the stored numbers into "File 2" format.

This is what I have so far:

```
#Extract numbers and store into an array

array = [] 
def extract_numbers(filename,start_pattern,end_pattern):  
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if start_pattern in line:
                for line in f:
                    numbers_wanted = line.split()
                    for number in numbers_wanted:
                        array.append(number)
                    if end_pattern in line:
                        break
extract_numbers("test.txt", "first_title", "second_title")
with open ("new_file.txt", 'w') as new_file:
    for number in array:
        print(number.format(???????)) #I need help here for this specific code.
```

All suggestions are welcome and please do not feel limited to the code I have provided. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [...] make every line (except the last line) of equal length?

From your question it's not clear what this equal length should be.
The longest line? The first line? A fixed target number?

Once you know the target length, a simple approach could be reading all values into a list in memory, and then print it out slice by slice.
For example if we can assume that the first line determines the target length, here's one way to do it, to get the same output as in your question:

```
import re

re_splitter = re.compile(r'\s+')

with open('input.txt') as fh:
    values = re_splitter.split(fh.readline().strip())
    target_len = len(values)

    for line in fh:
        values += re_splitter.split(line.strip())

    while values:
        print(' '.join(values[:target_len]))
        values = values[target_len:]
```

Another way, accumulating just enough data in memory as needed:

```
with open('input.txt') as fh:
    values = re_splitter.split(fh.readline().strip())
    target_len = len(values)

    for line in fh:
        if len(values) >= target_len:
            print(' '.join(values[:target_len]))
            values = values[target_len:]

        values += re_splitter.split(line.strip())

    if len(values) >= target_len:
        print(' '.join(values[:target_len]))
        values = values[target_len:]

    print(' '.join(values))
```